# Distributed Tensorflow fails : no devices matching that specification

Tags: tensorflow

I follow the example in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/distributed/ to create distributed TensorFlow with one ps and 2 workers. I only have 1 cpu with 8 cores in the machine I am testing on.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device to node 'save/RestoreV2_14': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:local/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0, /job:local/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0, /job:worker/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2_14 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_INT32], _device="/job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0"](save/Const, save/RestoreV2_14/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_14/shape_and_slices)]]
```

I already passed server.target as argument to sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session

> sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target)

Any idea what are the reasons for that ?

My training code is

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='tensorflow')
parser.add_argument('--job_name', dest='job_name')
parser.add_argument('--task_index', dest='task_index', default=0)
args = parser.parse_args()

ps_hosts = ['localhost:2222']
worker_hosts = ['localhost:2223', 'localhost:2224']
job_name = args.job_name
task_index = int(args.task_index)





# Create a cluster from the parameter server and worker hosts.
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

# Create and start a server for the local task.
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name=job_name, task_index=task_index)
if job_name == "ps":
    server.join()

elif job_name == "worker":
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % task_index,
        cluster=cluster)):
        total_input_features = len(train_x[0])
        x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, total_input_features])
        y = tf.placeholder('float')
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
        is_chief = (task_index == 0)
        prediction = neural_network_model(x, total_input_features, n_nodes_hl1,
                                          first_layer_activation,
                                          n_nodes_hl2,
                                          second_layer_activation)
        total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(prediction - y))
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(total_loss, global_step=global_step)

        init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

        sv = tf.train.Supervisor(
            is_chief=is_chief,
            logdir="/tmp/train_logs",
            init_op=init_op,
            global_step=global_step)

        print '******** ALL CREATED ********'


       # The supervisor takes care of session initialization, restoring from
       # a checkpoint, and closing when done or an error occurs.

        with sv.managed_session(server.target) as sess:

            # Loop until the supervisor shuts down or 1000000 steps have completed.
            step = 0
            while not sv.should_stop() and step < 1000000:
                # Run a training step asynchronously.
                # See `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` for additional details on how to
                # perform *synchronous* training.

                train_feed = {x: train_x, y: train_y}
                _, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step], feed_dict=train_feed)
                if step % 100 == 0:
                    print "Done step %d" % step

        sv.stop()
```

The complete stack trace is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "..../PycharmProjects/SparkProject/server_client_updated.py", line 162, in 
>       with sv.managed_session(server.target) as sess:
>
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in **enter**
>       return self.gen.next()
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 973, in managed_session
>       self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 801, in stop
>       stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 386, in join
>       six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 962, in managed_session
>       start_standard_services=start_standard_services)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 726, in prepare_or_wait_for_session
>       max_wait_secs=max_wait_secs)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 384, in wait_for_session
>       sess)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 467, in _try_run_local_init_op
>       sess.run(self._local_init_op)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>
> File "/Users/jabermo/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
>       feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
>       target_list, options, run_metadata)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
>
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'save/RestoreV2_14': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:local/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0, /job:local/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0, /job:worker/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0
>        [[Node: save/RestoreV2_14 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_INT32], _device="/job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0"](save/Const, save/RestoreV2_14/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_14/shape_and_slices)]]
>
> Caused by op u'save/RestoreV2_14', defined at:
>
> File "..../PycharmProjects/SparkProject/server_client_updated.py", line 127, in 
>       global_step=global_step)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 313, in **init**
>       self._init_saver(saver=saver)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 459, in _init_saver
>       saver = saver_mod.Saver()
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1051, in **init**
>       self.build()
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1081, in build
>       restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 675, in build
>       restore_sequentially, reshape)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 402, in _AddRestoreOps
>       tensors = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, saveable, preferred_shard)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 242, in restore_op
>       [spec.tensor.dtype])[0])
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 668, in restore_v2
>       dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
>       op_def=op_def)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2395, in create_op
>       original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
>
> File "..../tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1264, in **init**
>       self._traceback = _extract_stack()
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device to node 'save/RestoreV2_14': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:local/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0, /job:local/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0, /job:worker/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0
>        [[Node: save/RestoreV2_14 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_INT32], _device="/job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0"](save/Const, save/RestoreV2_14/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_14/shape_and_slices)]]

Comment: noticed that you're using v0.10. why not try v1.0 and follow the instructions here https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed

Comment: From the error message, it looks like the session is connecting to a server with a different configuration (two jobs called `"local"` and `"worker"`) from the one that you specified in your code. This is very strange... can you try printing out `cluster.as_cluster_def()` and including the result in your question?